# Could not find <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>

Tags: c++, grpc, bazel

What version of gRPC and what language are you using?

```
name = "com_github_grpc_grpc"
remote = "https://github.com/grpc/grpc"
commit = "bd0aa9a600a13cc988c6ebfd12deab8d1abcf171"
```

What operating system (Linux, Windows,...) and which version?
Ubuntu 18.04

What runtime / compiler are you using (e.g. python version or version of gcc)
bazel 1.0.1

What did you do?
Wrote a small grpc test application

in WORKSPACE

```
    workspace(name = "grpc_test")

    load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

    git_repository(
        name = "com_github_grpc_grpc",
        remote = "https://github.com/grpc/grpc",
        commit = "bd0aa9a600a13cc988c6ebfd12deab8d1abcf171",
    )

    load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_deps.bzl", "grpc_deps")
    grpc_deps()

    load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_extra_deps.bzl", "grpc_extra_deps")
    grpc_extra_deps()
```

in hello_world.proto

```
    syntax = "proto3";

    package hello_world;

    // The greeting service definition.
    service Greeter {
        // Sends a greeting
        rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
    }

    // The request message containing the user's name.
    message HelloRequest {
        string name = 1;
    }

    // The response message containing the greetings
    message HelloReply {
        string message = 1;
    }
```

in hello_world.proto BUILD

```
    package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

    load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:cc_grpc_library.bzl", "cc_grpc_library")

    cc_grpc_library(
        name = "hello_world",
        srcs = [":hello_world.proto"],
        deps = [],
    )
```

in server.cpp

```
    #include
    #include
    #include

    #include <grpc++/grpc++.h>

    #include "proto/hello_world.pb.h"
    #include "proto/hello_world.grpc.pb.h"

    using grpc::Server;
    using grpc::ServerBuilder;
    using grpc::ServerContext;
    using grpc::Status;
    using hello_world::HelloRequest;
    using hello_world::HelloReply;
    using hello_world::Greeter;
    using std::string;

    class GreeterServiceImpl final : public Greeter::Service {
        Status SayHello(
          ServerContext* context, 
          const HelloRequest* request,
          HelloReply* reply) override {
            string prefix("Hello ");
            reply->set_message(prefix + request->name());
            return Status::OK;
        }
    };

    void RunServer() {
        std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:10001");
        GreeterServiceImpl service;

        ServerBuilder builder;
        builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
        builder.RegisterService(&service);
        std::unique_ptr server(builder.BuildAndStart());
        std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;

        server->Wait();
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        RunServer();

        return 0;
    }
```

in server.cpp BUILD

```
    package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

    cc_binary(
        name = "server",
        srcs = ["server.cpp"],
        deps = [
            "//proto:hello_world",
        ],
    )
```

What did you expect to see?
I should be able to run
bazel build server:server --sandbox_debug

What did you see instead?

```
    INFO: Writing tracer profile to '/home/caixuanting/.cache/bazel/_bazel_caixuanting/56e1e1f496eedd6c32ee33d10eb39038/command.profile.gz'
    INFO: Analyzed target //client:client (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
    INFO: Found 1 target...
    ERROR: /home/caixuanting/grpc_test/client/BUILD:3:1: C++ compilation of rule '//client:client' failed (Exit 1) linux-sandbox failed: error executing command
    (cd /home/caixuanting/.cache/bazel/bazel_caixuanting/56e1e1f496eedd6c32ee33d10eb39038/sandbox/linux-sandbox/8/execroot/grpc_test &&
    exec env -
    PATH=/home/caixuanting/.vscode-server/bin/86405ea23e3937316009fc27c9361deee66ffbf5/bin:/home/caixuanting/.vscode-server/bin/86405ea23e3937316009fc27c9361deee66ffbf5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd
    TMPDIR=/tmp
    /home/caixuanting/.cache/bazel/bazel_caixuanting/install/0eaad79e03c843a15f078930a471406a/embedded_binaries/linux-sandbox -t 15 -w /home/caixuanting/.cache/bazel/bazel_caixuanting/56e1e1f496eedd6c32ee33d10eb39038/sandbox/linux-sandbox/8/execroot/grpc_test -w /tmp -w /dev/shm -D -- /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/client/objs/client/client.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/client/objs/client/client.pic.o' -fPIC -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin -iquote external/com_google_protobuf -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_protobuf -iquote external/zlib -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/zlib -iquote external/com_github_grpc_grpc -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_grpc_grpc -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools -isystem external/com_google_protobuf/src -isystem bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src -isystem external/zlib -isystem bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/zlib -isystem external/com_github_grpc_grpc/include -isystem bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/include -isystem external/com_github_grpc_grpc/src/core/ext/upb-generated -isystem bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/src/core/ext/upb-generated -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP="redacted"' '-D__TIME="redacted"' -c client/client.cpp -o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/client/_objs/client/client.pic.o)
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox.cc:154: linux-sandbox-pid1 has PID 4821
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:175: working dir: /home/caixuanting/.cache/bazel/_bazel_caixuanting/56e1e1f496eedd6c32ee33d10eb39038/sandbox/linux-sandbox/8/execroot/grpc_test
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:194: writable: /home/caixuanting/.cache/bazel/_bazel_caixuanting/56e1e1f496eedd6c32ee33d10eb39038/sandbox/linux-sandbox/8/execroot/grpc_test
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:194: writable: /tmp
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:194: writable: /dev/shm
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /dev
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /dev/pts
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount rw: /dev/shm
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /dev/mqueue
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /dev/hugepages
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /run
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /run/lock
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /run/snapd/ns
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /run/user/1000
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/kernel/security
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/unified
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/pstore
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/kernel/debug
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/kernel/config
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /sys/fs/fuse/connections
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /proc
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /snap/docker/384
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /snap/core/7917
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /snap/core/8039
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount ro: /var/lib/lxcfs
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount rw: /home/caixuanting/.cache/bazel/_bazel_caixuanting/56e1e1f496eedd6c32ee33d10eb39038/sandbox/linux-sandbox/8/execroot/grpc_test
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount rw: /home/caixuanting/.cache/bazel/_bazel_caixuanting/56e1e1f496eedd6c32ee33d10eb39038/sandbox/linux-sandbox/8/execroot/grpc_test
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount rw: /tmp
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:265: remount rw: /dev/shm
    src/main/tools/process-tools.cc:118: sigaction(32, &sa, nullptr) failed
    src/main/tools/process-tools.cc:118: sigaction(33, &sa, nullptr) failed
    client/client.cpp:5:10: fatal error: grpcpp/grpcpp.h: No such file or directory
    #include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:437: waitpid returned 2
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox-pid1.cc:457: child exited with code 1
    src/main/tools/linux-sandbox.cc:204: child exited normally with exitcode 1
    Target //client:client failed to build
    Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
    INFO: Elapsed time: 1.559s, Critical Path: 0.09s
    INFO: 0 processes.
    FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Where is the build rule for `//client:client` ?

Comment: My first guess is that you need to add the `grpc` library as a dependency to the `cc_binary` rules. Something along the lines of `"@com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc++"`. There are many different libraries in the main [build file](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILD). I don't know which one is the correct one, because I'm not familiar with `grpc`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved. I have to put dependency in deps=[] for gRPC.

Finally someone gives the answer.

I need add "@com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc++" in deps.

So stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

You did not installed the grpc itself (if you are building it then maybe `sudo make install` equivalent of bezel is required)

Comment: Are you familiar with Bazel and are you familiar with how Bazel import third party library? @fadedreamz

Comment: @NoviceCai sorry I am not familiar with Bazel. But I assumed it is equivalent to cmake. And the way in cmake it works is that, it pulls in the github repo, builds it and add the targets to current project or add the include directory to project manually.

Comment: That is exactly why I am asking you that question. Your assumption is not correct. Bazel is used to attain the same goal as cmake to make complicated compile easier. But they are quite different from how they achieve that. You don't need install the library manually when you import third party Bazel project.

Answer (score 0):

In your first `BUILD` file, your `cc_grpc_library` rule should be

```
    cc_grpc_library(
        name = "hello_world",
        srcs = ["relative/path/to/hello_world.proto"],
        deps = [],
    )
```

Notice that there is no colon in the `srcs` argument.

Your `srcs` argument starts with a colon, which is the Bazel syntax used for local rule dependencies passed to `deps`. For `src` arguments, use a colon-less relative filepath each source file. The [bazel example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/15c67e255b30c407aafcafe72d91bbaaad7a49dd/examples/BUILD#L31) should be helpful.

Comment: is hello_world.proto not a file?

Comment: It's a file, and you're correct to use it in that argument for that rule. You just have the wrong syntax. What does `bazel build proto:hello_world` tell you?